# Odoo ParseError when inheriting crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor

Tags: odoo, odoo-16

i want to be abel to midify CRM module so i inhertited it in my view:

```
    <odoo>
        <data>
            <record id="view_custom_crm_lead_form" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">custom.crm.lead.form</field>
                <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <!-- -->
                </field>
            </record>
        </data>
    </odoo>
```

the models and config files are all good since whenever i remove this line "" everything works but with it i get a "ParseError"

```
raise ParseError('while parsing %s:%s, somewhere inside\n%s' % (
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/d:/odoo/dev/general_it/views/sales_view.xml:4, somewhere inside

<record id="view_custom_crm_lead_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">custom.crm.lead.form</field>
            <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Purchase Receipt">
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent view used in your xml is wrong:
"`crm_case_form_view_oppor`" does not exist. The existing view is: `crm_lead_view_form`.
Moreover, you should use an `xpath` to extend the parent view with a `position`-attribute having the value : `inside` or `after`:

```xml
<record id="view_custom_crm_lead_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">custom.crm.lead.form</field>
            <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_lead_view_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//form/sheet/group[1]" position="inside">
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```